# cabal custom build flag

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a way to pass a custom flag to `cabal`.
E.g. within my `.cabal` file I want to write:

```
if !external
    cpp-options:      -DINCLUDE_EMBARGOED_IP
```

And then from the command line something like:

```
% cabal build -fexternal
```

(It's fine if I have to apply the flag at `configure`.)

Comment: Cabal supports such [flags](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations) - but you do have to apply the flag with `cabal configure -f <flag-name>`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cabal supports such [flags](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#configurations) - but you do have to apply the flag with cabal `configure -f <flag-name>`.